# cant include pagelayout of NPSP in changeset

Tags: deployment

I have a Page layout of NPSP Customized it and I am trying to deploy it to production but I can't able to include it to the Outbound changeset I can't even see it in the add changeset components I don't know why Please Help me to sort this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saldy the NPSP layout is part of a managed package so you won't be able to deploy it.  However, you should be able to clone it & make a new one that you can deploy at will.